# Vlookup in a range of numbers in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I want to do a range vlookup for e.g when i do a vlookup for 2,3,4 whatever number lies between the range in the given columns it will return the value given in A4.

I have tried multiple combinations but unable to achieve that.

Any help will be appreciated.

Sample data

A2   A3   A4

1    10   test

Comment: So your expected output from your ```LOOKUP``` would be ```test``` in your example? Could you share a Spreadsheet or an image *with no sensitive data* illustrating what you are trying to achieve (expected and actual output)? Thanks ! :D

Answer (score 1):

for a ranged vlookup you need to use 4th parameter and set it to 1. example:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, B:C, 2, 1)
```

see more at: **https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/123729/186471**